# How to count value change during a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that consists of one column that consists of `0` and `1`.

They are structured in this way `[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,]`.

My goal is to count only the first `1` in each repeating `1`s in a loop.

So in this example of `[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,]` it should be able to only count a total of `2`. How can I use a for loop and use an `if` condition and count this?

Comment: `s = pd.Series([0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,])` then `s.diff().eq(1).sum()`

Comment: @Erfan You should make that an answer and get credit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop:

```
out = [0]+[int(j-i==1) for i,j in zip(lst,lst[1:])]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Also, you can assign a `pd.Series` to a DataFrame column like:

```
df.col = (pd.Series(lst).diff()==1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

(As [@Erfan mentiond in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70328241/how-to-count-value-change-during-a-for-loop-in-python#comment124319844_70328241):)

```
>>> df
   col
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    1

>>> df['col'].diff().eq(1).sum()
2

>>> df['col'].diff().eq(1).astype(int)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    0
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is great. But I was hoping to use a for loop and if because I would to create a new data frame where from [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1] it can be transformed to [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0], where it basically only takes the first 1 of a repeating 1.

Comment: Okay @Drew, that's very easy.

Comment: Check now. I didn't realize you wanted that :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a messy way to do it where I can create a translated list and count the sum.

```
def FirstValue(data):      
for index, item in enumerate(data):    
    if item == 1:
        if data[index-1] == 1:
            counter.append(0)            
    if item == 1:
        if data[index-1] == 0:
            counter.append(1)            
    else:
        counter.append(0)
```

Comment: there is a much, much more efficient way to do this in my answer, which I just updated.